# Using jquery.form.js jquery plug in is causing my form to be submitted twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am using the jquery plugin named "jquery.form.js" (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) to be able to upload a file using Ajax in my ASP.Net MVC project.  The issue I am having is that when I press the submit button in the form, the controller action that handles the upload is being called twice.  The first time it is called the HttpPostedFileBase object is properly set with the uploaded file.  The second time it is called the HttpPostedFileBase object is set to Nothing.  I do not want the handler to be called twice.  How can I prevent the double post?

The View:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("Document", "NewDocument", Model, FormMethod.Post, New With {.enctype = "multipart/form-data", .id = "submitimage-form"})
 <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" />
 <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Accept" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" />

End Using

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("pageshow", '#choosenewdocument', function () {
      $("#submitimage-form").ajaxForm(function () {
      });
  });
</script>
```

The Controller handler:

```
<HttpPost()> _
Function Document(ByVal model As MaxDocument, fileInput As HttpPostedFileBase) As ActionResult
     ...
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `preventDefault`

```
<script>
$(document).on("pageshow", '#choosenewdocument', function () {
      $("#submitimage-form").ajaxForm({
         beforeSubmit: function() {
           return false;
         }
      });

  });
</script>
```

`preventDefault`(as the name suggests) prevents the default action from happening.

Comment: I tried your solution but I get the error:  Javascript runtime error:  Object doesn't support property or method 'preventDefault'.

Comment: After the form is submitted, are you rendering the same page? If so, it might be submitting your form on `pageshow`.

Comment: I just tried using `pageshow` and it did post my form twice. Why are you submitting your form on `pageshow`?

Comment: After the form is submitted I am going to a different page.  I put the submit in pageShow because in the documentation for the jquery plug in it said it should be executed after the DOM is ready and I typically use pageshow for that.  Where do you suggest it be put if not in pageshow?

Comment: I tried moving the submit to the pageinit and even put it outside of all events (just in the page script), and the double post still happens.  My theory about what is happening is that the first post (that is done correctly) is the Ajax submit via the jquery plugin.  The second post is a normal post that is failing because normally jquery mobile cannot upload files via ajax. If I wasn't using the jquery plugin at all, only the second post would be happening.

Comment: I tried your modified solution and now it is going to the submit handler, but the HttpPostedFileBase object is nill/nothing.  This is happening in IE 10.

Answer (score 0):

So, to prevent double submission when use jquery ajax, just put this in your form

> `action="javascript:null();"`

Comment: When I put this in my form and submit the form, I get a javascript runtime error:  Access is denied, in jquery 1.7.1.